# SQL - Error 'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined' in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, temp-tables

So I'm having some issues producing a query with multiple temporary tables.

First I created the temporary tables.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE DIDV (DID VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO DIDV VALUES ('8090630909077434001');
INSERT INTO DIDV VALUES ('7471990179373590001');
INSERT INTO DIDV VALUES ('7605256906013877001');
INSERT INTO DIDV VALUES ('1604387368720407001');
INSERT INTO DIDV VALUES ('3512739534818409001');

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE KEYW (KEW VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Corporate Insurance Pol%');
INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Tax Return%');
INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Audit%');
INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Corporate Governance%');
INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Board%');
INSERT INTO KEYW VALUES ('%Shareholder%');
```

Then I write my query as follows. It seems like a simple query. However, I get the error 'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined'. I don't know if I can do a join of the 2 temporary tables, especially they do not have any relationship. I just want to query result where the unique id's are in the DIDV table and where the title and comment columns do not contain the KEW fields.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DID) DID, TO_CHAR(DROOTPARENTID) PARENTID, DBARCODE, 
DDOCTITLE, XCOMMENTS, XDIVISION, DEXTOBJECTTYPE
FROM PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA, DIDV, KEYW
WHERE PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.DID = DIDV.DID 
AND PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.DDOCTITLE NOT LIKE KEYW.KEW 
AND PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.XCOMMENTS NOT LIKE KEYW.KEW;
```

Any help understanding this is appreciated.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: `DID` in the select list needs a table alias. Also, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A table `DIDV` contains a column named `DID`
A table `URM_EXTITEMS_PSA` also contains a column named `DID` (I know this because a where condition contains a clause `WHERE PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.DID = DIDV.DID` ).

---

A select statement in your query contains an expression referencing the column `DID`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DID) ....
```

Oracle doesn't really know (I don't know too) which `DID` do you want to get in a result - the 'DID' column which comes from `DIDV` table or the `DID` column which comes from  `URM_EXTITEMS_PSA` table. Therefore Oracle throws an error `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.

---

Just append an aliast to this `DIV` column in the select clause, either `DIDV` or `URM_EXTITEMS_PSA`, in this way:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DIDV.DID) ....
```

---

I know that WHERE clause contains `PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.DID = DIDV.DID` and actually both `DID`s are equal, so Oracle should be smart enaugh to say `Oh, yes, he wrote PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA.DID = DIDV.DID, so I can pick DID from any table` ....
Unfortunatelu Oracle is not so smart (maybe they improve this in a new version ?), and for now you must append an alias or a table name.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is very insightful. I did however add an alias to PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA. I used PS, because for some reason Oracle is very picky of what you use as Alias. Also I couldn't use Table AS Alias. I had to do Table Alias instead.

__SELECT 
PS.DID, 
PS.DROOTPARENTID, 
PS.DBARCODE, 
PS.DDOCTITLE, 
PS.XCOMMENTS, 
PS.XDIVISION, 
PS.DEXTOBJECTTYPE
FROM 
PSA.URM_EXTITEMS_PSA PS, DIDV, KEYW
WHERE PS.DID = DIDV.DID 
AND PS.DDOCTITLE NOT LIKE KEYW.KEW
AND PS.XCOMMENTS NOT LIKE KEYW.KEW;__

Comment: It would seem like my query completely ignored the requirement of PS.DID = DIDV.DID. Why would it do that? It produced way more rows than the 30,000 I used in DIDV.DID.